# Subclassing document in separate collections in Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a collection in Mongoengine with long list of fields which contains some documents:

```
class Component(Document):
    name = StringField(unique=True)
    title = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField(default='')
    # And so on...
```

Now I want another collection similar to the first collection with some extra stuffs. So I used `allow_inheritance` in the first collection for subclassing:

```
class Component(Document):
    name = StringField(unique=True)
    title = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField(default='')
    # And so on...
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class ChildComponent(Component):
    extra_stuff = StringField()
```

But as the [documents](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document) mentions, this way all the data will save in the same collection.

So I tried adding [`abstract`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#abstract-classes) to meta in the parent document, so I can have two separate collections.

```
class Component(Document):
    name = StringField(unique=True)
    title = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField(default='')
    # And so on...
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True, 'abstract': True}
```

But now when I try to get the documents from `Component` using `Component.objects().all()` I get this error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Component' has no attribute 'objects'

Should I create a base document and abstract my two collections from it or there's simpler way to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Even if I create a base class and inherit both classes from it:

```
class BaseComponent(Document):
    name = StringField(unique=True)
    title = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField(default='')
    # And so on...
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True, 'abstract': True}

class Component(BaseComponent):
    pass

class ChildComponent(BaseComponent):
    extra_stuff = StringField()
```

When I try `Component.objects.all()`, the result will be and empty list.

**UPDATE 2**
If I add a `component` with `.save()` I can get that one with `Component.objects.all()`. But what about the rest of the documents which are already saved in that collection? How can I restore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I got no answer, I've found a work around for it. When using `abstract` in meta, the child collections get an extra field called `_cls` with the collection name as value. So I used pymongo to update existing documents with a `_cls` field and value equals to the collection name like this:

```
 db["component"].update_many({}, {"$set": {"_cls": "Component"}}, upsert=False, array_filters=None)
```

After doing this, now I can get the documents using mongoengine `Component.objects().all()` query.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'abstract': True` and remove `'allow_inheritance': True`.
For more details [see this](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=string#abstract-classes).

Answer (score 0):

I had very same issue, the [Vahid Panahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15240833/vahid-panahi) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67860028/5444623) is ok, i've tried it. Full example here with optional collection names:

```py
from mongoengine import *

connect('test')

class BaseTest(Document):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    name = StringField()

    meta = {
        'abstract': True,
        'allow_inheritance': True
    }

class Test(BaseTest):
    pass
    # meta = {
    #     'collection': 'Test',
    # }

class TestExtended(BaseTest):
    text = StringField()

    # meta = {
    #     'collection': 'TestExtended'
    # }

model1 = Test()
model1.name = 'foo'
model1.save()

model2 = TestExtended()
model2.name = 'bar'
model2.text = 'foo bar story'
model2.save()

for model in Test.objects.all():
    print(f"Test: {model.name}")
for model in TestExtended.objects.all():
    print(f"TestExtended: {model.name}")
```

Will print:

```
Test: foo
TestExtended: bar
```

And in fact models are stored in different collections.